# Error in console shows error in main.js on not specific file where it occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a React project and I am trying to debug certain features. I've noticed when I get an error and I inspect it in Chrome DevTools, it only shows error in `main.js:82145`. As you can see this is the `js` file for the entire project (error occurs on line 82145). This is quite difficult to debug. When you normally run a React project and an error occurs, it tells you in which file specifically it occurs. For instance `AddUser.js:52`. My question is what the reason will be why my current project doesn't show the exact file? The project uses Grunt and the only thing I can think of is that it compiles to a `main.js` file and doesn't "know" about the rest of the files but only the `main.js`.

Here is a screenshot of my current error:

[image]

Comment: Is the the "built" version of the script? When you build it, everything is compiled for production / deployment so you lose variable names, file names. You can try the React DevTools extension, it might help a bit with the components

Comment: Yes, our Grunt task writes the `main.js` file (which is the built version). Okay this makes sense, so normally when running a React project it will be served (not from the built file) and that is why you see the specific files where the error occurs? But I will probably sit with the same problem, because the built version doesn't know about the file structure?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I would suggest to deploy the development build, the only real difference is in size (i.e. bandwidth used to serve the JS), but it would be useful if the bug is only occurring in production environment.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much. It is definitely much clearer now as to what is happening.